# Processing huge amount of text data in memory

Tags: python, algorithm, data-structures, bigdata

I am trying to process ~20GB of data on a Ubuntu system having 64 GB of RAM.

This step is a part of a some preprocessing steps to generate feature vectors for training an ML algo.

The original implementation(written by someone in my team) had lists in it. It does not scale up well as we add more training data. It is something like this.

```
all_files = glob("./Data/*.*")
file_ls = []

for fi in tqdm(all_files):
    with open(file=fi, mode="r", encoding='utf-8', errors='ignore') as f:
        file_ls.append(f.read())
```

This runs into a memory error(process gets killed).
So I though I should try out replacing the list based thing with tries

```
def insert(word):
    cur_node = trie_root
    for letter in word:
        if letter in cur_node:
            cur_node = cur_node[letter] 
        else:
            cur_node[letter] = {} 
            cur_node = cur_node[letter]
    cur_node[None] = None

trie_root = {}

for fi in tqdm(all_files):
    with open(file=fi, mode="r", encoding='utf-8', errors='ignore') as f:
        insert(f.read().split())
```

This too gets killed. The above is a demo code that I have written to capture the memory footprint of the objects. The worse part is that the demo code for list runs standalone but the demo code for trie gets killed, leading me to believe that this implementation is worse than the list implementation.

My goal is to write some efficient code in Python to resolve this issue.

Kindly help me solve this problem.

EDIT: 
Responding to @Paul Hankin, the data processing involves first taking up each file and adding a generic placeholder for terms with a normalized term frequency greater than 0.01 after which each file is splitted into a list and a vocabulary is calculated taking all the processed files into consideration.

Comment: The list implementation would be largely offloaded to C (in cython) - your custom trie would be wholly in Python so both performance and likely memory is going to be orders of magnitude worse. TL;DR: you need to looks at something like Pandas

Comment: Can you help me improve the trie implementation. I think it would be cool if I get this integrated(I would feel really proud :) )

Comment: Pandas isn't likely to help. It's not very memory-efficient; the creator of Pandas has listed memory inefficiency as one of his big regrets, and gives a rule of thumb that [you usually need RAM about 5 to 10 times the size of your data set](https://wesmckinney.com/blog/apache-arrow-pandas-internals/) to use Pandas.

Comment: I don’t think you can. Don’t forget, Python (well cython) is a bunch of glue code over the top of highly optimized C. The performance of Python (and Pandas, TF etc) comes from C, the Python is slow as treacle. Unless you want to write an actually performing trie library in C (or C++, Rust etc) you’re going to have to find one and integrate it. Pandas is your best bet.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica but the point of Pandas, at least in my limited understanding, is support for offloading processing to high performance native code and windowing of files and data structures during processing - with the express purpose of allowing processing of data far in excess of RAM. Which, realistically, is the only viable solution. If the OP was writing C#, Java, C etc then I’d say it was worth optimising - you can get that data into memory if careful. Pure Python? Not a chance.

Comment: Do you have some reason to believe that incremental encoding will meaningfully compress your data?

Comment: Any chance I can accomplish this using mmap, shelve or dbm?

Comment: @BoristheSpider: Pandas is designed for in-memory datasets. Maybe you're thinking of a different library.

Comment: What about all the data frame/window stuff? I guess I’m assuming that storing 20GB of words in memory isn’t the end goal of the exercise and that processing the file windowed will allow for population of the feature vectors without pulling everything into RAM at once.

Comment: I guess the real question here is: is the processing you want to do to these words distributive? If so, just map reduce it.

Comment: @BoristheSpider: Pandas dataframes are in-memory. It's not like a Spark DataFrame or a table in a traditional database. I don't think there's any file windowing stuff either. You can process [rolling windows over DataFrames and Series objects](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/window.html), but that's still in memory.

Comment: If you don't say what processing you're doing on the data in these files, you can't expect a good answer about how to handle them efficiently.

Comment: A naive trie implementation is almost certainly going to occupy more memory than a list implementation. The child pointer overhead is huge. I'm not familiar with Python's text encoding, but many other languages store text in Unicode: two bytes per character. So that'll blow your minimum memory requirement from 20 GB to 40GB. I suspect you'll have to come up with a way to process this data as a stream rather than holding it all in memory at once.

Answer (score 0):

One of the simple solutions to this problem might be to NOT store data in a list or any data structure. You can try writing these data to a file while doing the reading.

Comment: I understand this could be the final solution but I was trying to avoid this as it will make the preprocessing slow. When I mean slow, the preprocessing code takes 2-3 days to complete on 224000 files. I guess this will take around 4 days. I have been thinking about parallellizing some portions of the code. I guess I will keep some hope for some better DS based answer and start with db implementation.